# Receiving an array with a specific key using ngrx/selector and ngrx/entities

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

How can I use the selector to get data only with a certain key?

That is, I have 4 menus, each with a specific `catalogCode`, the user gets a list for a specific menu from the server on click. Each element of this list has an `id = code + catalogCode`. That is, the `catalogCode` of all elements of this menu will be the same.
So how do I get a list of items for a particular `catalogCode` from the store?

**I'm trying to do so**: `selectByCatalogCode`

```
export const selectCatalogItemState: MemoizedSelector<object, State> = createFeatureSelector('CatalogItem');
export const selectCatalogItemAll: MemoizedSelector<object, CatalogItem[]> = createSelector(selectCatalogItemState, selectAll);
export const selectByCatalogCode = () => createSelector(selectCatalogItemAll, (entities: CatalogItem[], props: { catalogCode: string }) => entities[props.catalogCode]);
```

But this does not work when used in a component, always displays an undefined value

```
  getCatalogItems(catalogCode: string) {
    this.catalogItemStore.dispatch(new CatalogItemStoreAction.LoadByCatalog({catalogCode: catalogCode}));
    this.catalogItemStore.select(CatalogItemStoreSelector.selectByCatalogCode(), {catalogCode: catalogCode}).subscribe(
      a => console.log(a)
    );
  }
```

**catalog-item.ts**

```
export class CatalogItem {
  constructor(public code: string,
              public catalogCode: string,
              public title: string,
              public data: object) {
  }
}
```

I have provided only part of the code. If necessary, I can provide the code of the entire store.

**effect.ts**

```
  @Effect()
  getCatalogEffect$: Observable<Action> = this.action$
    .pipe(
      ofType<featureAction.GetByCatalog>(featureAction.ActionTypes.GET_BY_CATALOG),
      switchMap(action => this.store.select(CatalogItemStoreSelector.selectByCatalogCode(action.payload.catalogCode))
        .pipe(
          take(1),
          filter(catalogItems => !catalogItems),
          map(() => new featureAction.LoadByCatalog({catalogCode: action.payload.catalogCode})),
        )
      )
    );
  @Effect()
  loadByCatalog$: Observable<Action> = this.action$
    .pipe(
      ofType<featureAction.LoadByCatalog>(featureAction.ActionTypes.LOAD_BY_CATALOG),
      switchMap(action => this.catalogItemService.listByCatalog(action.payload.catalogCode)
        .pipe(
          map(catalogItems => new featureAction.LoadByCatalogSuccess({catalogItems: catalogItems})),
          catchError(error => of(new featureAction.LoadByCatalogError({error: error}))),
        )
      )
    );
```

**catalogs-list.component.ts**

```
  getCatalogItems(catalogCode: string) {
    this.catalogItemStore.dispatch(new CatalogItemStoreAction.GetByCatalog({catalogCode: catalogCode}));
  }
```

Comment: Is it even possible to get it?

Comment: Are you trying to pass a parameter to your selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your selector, if you want to get the object which match your catalogCode, use a filter.

TS:

```
this.catalogItemStore.select(CatalogItemStoreSelector.selectByCatalogCode(catalogCode)).subscribe(
      a => console.log(a)
    );
```

Selector:

```
export const selectByCatalogCode = (catalogCode: string) => createSelector(selectCatalogItemAll, (entities: CatalogItem[]) => entities.filter((item: CatalogItem) => item.catalogCode === catalogCode));
```

Comment: Thank! Unfortunately, I can only try tomorrow. I think it will work